# How to retrieve and read large text files efficiently in Android

Tags: android-layout, android, textview

I am planning on creating a bible app. As you know, this will involve massive text files. And as a result if poorly implemented, the application can be quite inefficient.

I am thinking of storing the large files in raw folder but I feel that this is counter-intuitive as a result of the heavy content. And would it be feasible to use a multi-line textview to display the text files from the raw folder?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am really desperate as I have been poring over this issue for  days!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thoughts anyone? would appreciate the help!!

Comment: How do you plan to index the content? That will guide your storage and access strategy.

Comment: Tony I am planning on using a listView to index the content, that way if user selects say Genesis this opens new activity with the corresponding verses and when selects verse opens new activity opening the text file, I hope this make sense

Comment: You can not store anything in raw folder at dynamic times.see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732907/most-efficient-way-to-store-and-retrieve-large-amounts-of-text-data-in-android/11733014#11733014

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the text into multiple, smaller HTML files that you can then load into a `WebView`?

Comment: Tony how so, could you provide me an example please?